# Enter a value in cell on click using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to enter alternate values of array of 2 elements into the cells of my table. 
I am doing this by following code.

```
var arr= new Array("X","O");  
var index=0;
  $('td').click(function()
    {
        if($(this).html())
        {
            alert("Use empty slots");
        }
        else
        {
            var i=index % 2;
            $(this).html("<b>"+ arr[i] +"</b>");
            index++;
        }
    }
    );
```

It seems function inside click() is not being called.
What is wrong with my code?

Comment: is the td s are dynamic

Comment: have you wrapped this `click()` into `$(document).ready(function(){...});`?

Comment: Try using delegates. Change `$('td').click(function(){ ... });` to `$(document).on('click','td', function(){ .... });`

Comment: Yes the td is dynamically generated.

Comment: You should use delegates then

Comment: use $(document).on('click', 'td', function() {

Comment: Yes n-dru it is wrapped inside $(document).ready(function(){...});

Comment: Thanks Anoop Joshi and Think Different. It worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this if you know the id or class of your table

```
$("#tableId").on("click", "td", function() {
     //your code here
   });
```